# Expanding a SAP Tree

Tags: automation, vbscript, hp-uft, sap-gui

I'm using UFT (vbscript) to automate a process between SAP and a Web page. Using SAP transaction `S_ALR_87013534`, I have a piece of code in UFT that will expand the tree completely and extract the value associated with one of the order numbers:

```
set tree = SAPGuiSession("Session").SAPGuiWindow("Execute Drilldown Report").SAPGuiTree("TableTreeControl")
tree.OpenItemContextMenu "PRJ "&projNum,"PRJ "&projNum
tree.SelectMenuItemById "&EXPAND"
tree.SelectNode "PRJ "&projNum
colKey_plan1 = getColNameFromTitle(tree, "Plan 2--Overall")
rowContainingOrdNum = findBudget(tree, ordNum)
plannedProjectBudget = tree.Object.GetItemText(tree.Object.GetAllNodeKeys(rowContainingOrdNum(0)), colKey_plan1)

Function getColNameFromTitle(tree, title)
    set colNames = tree.Object.GetColumnNames
    For i = 1 To (colNames.length-1)
        selectedColTitle = tree.Object.GetColumnTitleFromName(colNames(i))
        If selectedColTitle = title Then
            getColNameFromTitle = colNames(i)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Function

Function findBudget(tree, ordNum)
    rowContainingOrdNum = Array()
    Set columnNames = tree.Object.GetColumnNames()
    set columnKeys = tree.Object.GetColumnCol(columnNames(0))
    For i = 1 To (columnKeys.length-1)
        If InStr(columnKeys(i), ordNum)>0 Then
            AddItem rowContainingOrdNum, i
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    findBudget = rowContainingOrdNum
End Function

Function AddItem(arr, val)
    ReDim Preserve arr(UBound(arr) + 1)
    arr(UBound(arr)) = val
    AddItem = arr
End Function
```

This works perfectly, but when I use a different report, `S_ALR_87013543`, it's still recognised as a tree but the above code doesn't work as there is no EXPAND option at the Object heading. I'm not very familiar with SAP and all their trees and how to use automation with it, so any guidance or tips are appreciated.

Left is the report I need to expand, and right is the report the code works with:

[image]
[image]

Comment: You are asking if someone knows what these transaction codes are "made of". I think you'd better give more information about the current VBScript issue. Please provide minimal reproducible example + what error you currently experience, at what line.

Comment: I don't think there's an issue with my current code, it just doesn't apply for a different type of SAP tree. So I just need to figure out how to work with the second tree

Comment: You can only automate the actions which are possible for users. Do you really have a context menu item with "&EXPAND" function code in `S_ALR_87013543` screen? If no, then you can't automate it. If your question is how to click the "little arrow button" in front of the tree nodes to expand their children, then please edit your question and I can answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
   Set TreeObj = SAPGuiSession("Session").SAPGuiWindow("Actual/Plan/Variance").SAPGuiTree("TableTreeControl").Object
    Set AllValues = TreeObj.GetAllNodeKeys
    Count = AllValues.Count
    Found = 0
    For i = 0 to Count-1
        NodeText = TreeObj.GetNodeTextByKey(AllValues(i))
        If NodeText = WBSelement Then
            Found = 1
            Exit For
        End if
    Next
    If Found = 1 Then
         SAPGuiSession("Session").SAPGuiWindow("Actual/Plan/Variance").SAPGuiTree("TableTreeControl").SelectNode WBS
    End If
```